# How to keep intermediate container running in Docker?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a `Dockerfile`, which looks like this:

```
FROM centos/httpd
COPY ./aquarium-javascript/html/ /var/www/html/
RUN yum install -y java-11-openjdk
COPY ./aquarium_fish-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./
COPY ./aquarium_species-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./
COPY ./aquarium_gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./
COPY ./wrapper.sh ./
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 80
RUN bash wrapper.sh
```

The `wrapper.sh` looks like this:

```
java -jar aquarium_fish-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
sleep 7;
java -jar aquarium_species-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
sleep 7;
java -jar aquarium_gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
sleep 7;
```

When I run the java files manually using the `sudo docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash` it works, but when I do it in the `wrapper.sh` it doesn't. I figured that it must be like this because the intermediate container is removed after executing the java files. Is there any way to stop this from happening? Or am I interpreting this situation wrong?

Comment: Intermediate container?

Comment: Note that the only purpose of a Dockerfile is to create a Docker image. It's not expected to start any persistent service. If you want to interact with your code, you need to start a container using `docker run`.

Comment: `when I do it in the wrapper.sh it doesn't` `wrapper.sh` will be executed inside the docker container, why would you `docker exec` from "inside" it? What command did you execute exactly?

Comment: The last `RUN` ought to be a `CMD`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman When I change RUN to CMD even the httpd stops working. I'm running it like this `CMD ["bash", "wrapper.sh"]`.

Comment: You probably want to run this as three separate containers; you should be able to `docker run your-image java -jar aquarium_fish-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` to override the image's default `CMD`.  You may want to build it as three separate images.  Setting this up using Docker Compose could help make it simpler to rebuild and launch this set of containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: You don't. `RUN` commands are executed during image build and in ephemeral containers with the purpose of modifying some part of the image.  They're supposed to finish quickly so you can eventually obtain the finished container image. If you want things to be long-running, you use `docker run` for that. The command to be run by `docker run` can be set in the `Dockerfile`, with either `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`.

As  Wojtek Wencel suggests, you can obtain a long running container by changing `RUN bash wrapper.sh` into `CMD ["bash", "wrapper.sh"]`, (adding a `wait` at the end of `wrapper.sh`), and running the image with `docker run --rm aquarium` after building it with `docker build -t aquarium`. The problem with this approach is that there won't be any neat handling when one of the processes fails, and the log output will be intermingled, sometimes with no easy way to tell the lines apart.

As David Maze suggested, it would be more appropriate to give each process its own container, and run them together with docker-compose. There are various ways of doing that, I tend to:

- Change `RUN bash wrapper.sh` to `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar"]`
- Use a `docker-compose.yaml` like

```yaml
version: "2.4"
services:
  fish:
    command: aquarium_fish-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    build:
      context: .
  species:
    command: aquarium_species-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    build:
      context: .
  gateway:
    command: aquarium_gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 80:80 # Guessing here.
```

That would also make `wrapper.sh` unnecessary.

This is a fairly standard usecase, so there's a myriad ways to do this. You could also keep `wrapper.sh` and pass the service name into the container as an environment variable or argument to it.